# Musar Study - recommendations

Tags: product-recommendation, mussar-ethics

In our weekly chavrusa on Musar, we (retired baalei batim) have covered over several years:

Michtav MeiEliyohu, Sifsei Chaim, Alei Shur and we are about to conclude Orchos Chaim.

We would welcome suggestions for our next study. The content should be relevant to our times.

Comment: What area of mussar are you looking to explore? Tikkun hamiddos, emunah etc.

Comment: דעת חכמה ומוסר של רבי ירוחם ליבוביץ

Comment: The classic mussar sefarim are timeless. Have you thought about learning Mishlei?

Comment: @N.T. Yes, specifically with the Gr"a.  I found this sample page on Hebrewbooks.com; 
https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=57967&st=&pgnum=32&hilite= Do you know of another edition perhaps with translation?

Comment: There are newer editions with better print. If you have a seforim store neaby you could check if they can get you one with a translation; I don't see it with google.

Comment: Michtav miEliyahhu. Shiurei Daas. Not a full book, but I highly recommend anyone who learns Mussar to see  R Shimon Shkop's haqdamah of Shaarei Yosher. (I hear Mosaica put out a full book based on it. But I am way too paternal to give you an objective assessment. Not for your chavrusah either. While heavy, it's neither in Hebrew nor a "primary text".)

Answer (score 4):

There are a plethora of really phenomenal seforim that are still relevant to this day and age

If you are looking at taking mussar from the weekly parsha, my personal faves are:

- Sichos Mussar by Rav Chaim Shmulevitz zt"l
- Darchei Mussar by Rav Yaakov Aryeh Neiman zt"l

Tikkun Hamiddos

- Orchos Tzaddikim - an oldie but a goodie :-)
- Sefer Olam Hamiddos

Other classics with a modern grounding:

- Daas Chochmo Umussar by Rav Yerucham Levovitz zt"l
- Ohr Avigdor on Chovas Halevavos by Rav Avigdor Miller zt"l

*More to follow*

Answer (score 2):

Try [Madreigas Ha'adam](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/madreigas-haadam/36369), from the Alter of Novardok. With the exception of the first section (which is fascinating in its own right), the sefer is filled with psychological insights from a mussar perspective. It's in line with the other sefarim you've done as well, because just like R' Dessler, the Alter of Novardok was a talmid of the Alter of Kelm.

Answer (score 1):

1. The sefer [Bircas HaTorah, Bringing Torah To Life And Life To Torah; Shiurei HaMusar, by Rabbi Nissim Tagger](https://www.feldheim.com/bircas-hatorah-bringing-torah-to-life-and-life-to-torah) has almost 277 pages of shiurei mussar. It is categorised by parasha.

The book's description reads as follow:

> In reading and explaining a pasuk or a statement of Chazal, we must ask ourselves whether we are pumping our philosophy into Chazal or extracting our philosophy from Chazal.
>
> In this sefer, Rabbi Nissim Tagger, the Rosh Yeshiva of Yeshivas
> Bircas HaTorah applies his unique, incisive and methodological
> approach in learning Gemara to the pesukim of the parashah, the
> meforshim, and the Baalei Mussar, asking simple and straightforward
> questions to unveil a deep understanding of the Torah, before driving
> home the powerful mussar lessons contained within.
>
> Each shiur has been learned, challenged, defended and hammered again
> and again, and is a reflection of the Rosh Yeshiva’s unwavering
> mission to reveal the grandeur in every word of Torah and to
> personalize the powerful messages being communicated to shape our
> worldview — striving to be the person that Hashem longs for each of us
> to be. Each shiur effectively brings renewed life to the Torah, and
> brings the Torah into our lives.

2. @Dov mentioned Sefer Olam HaMiddos. I have it, wonderful sefer. In it, the Madreigas HaAdam is often quoted and explained. ArtScroll recently released an English version of it [(MADREIGAS HAADAM - DARCHEI HABITACHON)](https://zbermanbooks.com/madreigas-haadam-darchei-habitachon)
3. [Tomer Devorah Elucidated](https://zbermanbooks.com/tomer-devorah-elucidated)
4. [Shaar Habitachon - Gate of Trust](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5407154/jewish/Shaar-Habitachon-Gate-of-Trust.htm); newest edition from Kehos Publication. The blurb writes:

> Gate of Trust takes us on a transformational journey towards genuine trust, guiding us to a state of tranquil reliance on the all-powerful and compassionate G-d. Studying this vital work shows us how to confront and even transform unpredictable and challenging events by exercising and implementing the messages of genuine unyielding trust in G-d.

5. The [Maamarim Ki Imcha Ha'Slicha and Ani Le'Dodi 5709](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2330428/jewish/Mastery-Over-Self.htm) by the Frierdiker Rebbe.
6. [Iggeres HaRamban](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422605165.html);  Rabbi Avrohom Chaim Feuer ArtScroll
7. [Reb Michel's Shmuessen](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899066387.html); Rabbi Michel Barenbaum (author)

> The epitome of the Mussar masters of old, Rabbi Michel Barenbaum has raised generations of devoted disciples in over four decades as Mashgiach of Mesivtha Tifereth Jerusalem. Now for the first time, this great sage's wisdom and inspiration is available in English. He speaks from the heart to the soul. This is a book of exceptional appeal, warmth, and introspection.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your list of previous studies, I would recommend Pachad Yitzcak by Rav Hutner z"l, and Matnas Chaim and other works by Rav Mattisyahu Salomon shlit"a.